# response from a server to an android application

Tags: android

Iam developing an android app that needs to get a respond from the server .
The app am developing is a complaint managment system, where the user write a complaint and call the server with a rest api to be stored in a database, the admin then view the complaint and replay to the user, my question is how to transfer the respone back to the client ? And how could i implement this feature properly .

Comment: The admin will send an email.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you Google Cloud Messaging to implmement push notifications.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

And a very easy alternative, if you are new developing Android apps, is Parse: https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications